# How to resize UIA window for UIAutomation purposes, using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, automation, ui-testing

I created some coded UI tests for a Win32 application with Visual Studio. I would like the window size to stay consistent so I want it to resize the application window after I launch the application.

I am launching the application like this:

```
using (ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.UIMap.launchReaderParams.ExePath,
                                   this.UIMap.launchReaderParams.AlternateExePath))   
{
```

I have looked into possible ways of doing this and found a method called `SetWindowPos()`. However I am unsure of how to use this because it requires the window handle as one of its parameters. How could I obtain the window handle?

Also, is there a better way to resize my application window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the position and size to the application under test by supplying a [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to CreateProcess.  Now, of course, your problem is to get that `STARTUPINFO` structure to `CreateProcess`.  I don't know how your `Launch` method is implemented, but at some point it's going to call either `CreateProcess` (good; all you have to do is initialize the `STARTUPINFO` structure appropriately) or `ShellExecute` (bad, because you can't specify a `STARTUPINFO` structure).

Comment: This sounds solid but I just ended up using the SetWindowsPos function. I returned the application handle by searching through current processes.